# Receiving warning message with a function in WordPress .. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: wordpress

Here's my function,

```
class emailer {
function notifyHeart($post_ID)  {
$interests = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'interests');
$to = the_author_meta( 'user_email', get_current_user_id() );
$post = get_post($post_ID);

foreach($interests as $interest) {
  if(has_tag($interest, $post)) {
    $email = $to;
    mail($email, "An article about Heart", 'A new post has been published about heart.');
    break;
  }
}
 }
 }
  add_action('publish_post', array('emailer', 'notifyHeart'));
```

The error comes up after publishing a post and only happens when I include

```
$to = the_author_meta( 'user_email', get_current_user_id() );
```

If I include this instead,

```
$to = "email@email.com";
```

No Warnings occur. Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a different WP function:

```
// This actually echos the result right to the page, hence the headers error.
the_author_meta()

// Whereas this lets you capture the value into your $to variable:
get_the_author_meta()
```

Comment: That's actually a good rule of thumb to remember with Wordpress as it's used across several functions like the_content() and get_the_content().

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the heads up, definitely going to keep that in the mind in the future.